# How to access environment variables from Kubernetes pods in React/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, kubernetes

We're defining some environment variables in kubernetes pods and when i try to use them in either node or React FE code using process.env.TEST(as TEST is present in env as secrets), i always got undefined but when i see variables on pods it was there.

Is there any other way to access those variables or we need to do something explicitly either on Node.js or React.js.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The secrets for frontend service like react, secrets must to be passed during the build time i.e while building the docker image

we build react apps and also call secrets from the vault during build time and it works.

pipeline steps for frontend apps should be :

1. download secrets from the vault(secret manager)
2. build docker image
3. Deployment

hope this helps you